# Print an error message when there is the input parameter is null and terminate the procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am writing a SQL stored procedure, there is one input parameter which is required. How could I output a text error message when the parameter is null at the beginning of the procedure and terminate the procedure?

```
IF NULLIF(@P_Currentperiod, '') IS NULL
    BEGIN 
    --????

    RETURN
    END
ELSE
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Answer (score 5):

If we have option to restrict `NULL` values in SP `paramaters` it will be good but we don't have such option so try something like this

```
if @P_Currentperiod is null 
Begin
    raiserror('P_Currentperiod parameter cannot be null', 15, 1) 
    RETURN -- To terminate the procedure.
END
```

- **RAISERROR** : To notify whats wrong
- **RETURN**    : To terminate the procedure

**Update :**

For the people looking for same option in Sql server 2012 or greater use [**THROW**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ee677615.aspx)

```
if @P_Currentperiod is null 
Begin
    THROW 51000, 'P_Currentperiod parameter cannot be null.', 1;
END
```

> Raises an exception and transfers execution to a CATCH block of a
>   TRY…CATCH construct in SQL Server 2016.

**Syntax**

> THROW [ { error_number | @local_variable },
>           { message | @local_variable },
>           { state | @local_variable } ]  [ ; ]

Comment: You still need a `return`.

Comment: @MartinSmith -Sorry I didn't get the point. Why we need `RETURN` here.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Added. I thought `raiserror` alone will stop the procedure. Thanks for the info

Comment: @MartinSmith - Thanks man you are great :). This is why i love SO

Comment: Thanks. FWIW `THROW` would exit the proc but not available to the OP as they are < 2012.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Updated the answer. Again thanks for sharing :)